Coefficient of chromatic polynomial of connected graph is at most number of spanning trees

Let $G$ be a connected graph and write $\chi(G,k) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-i}a_{i}k^{i}$ for the chromatic polynomial of $G$. Let $t(G)$ denote the number of spanning trees in $G$. Show that $a_{1} \leq t(G)$.

I somewhat understand the statement but I'm having trouble proving it. I have shown that \begin{equation} t(G) = t(G-e) + t(G/e)\end{equation}where $G/e$ is obtained from $G$ by contracting the edge $e$. It seems that there is some relation between this and the deletion-contraction of the graph $G$: \begin{equation}\chi(G, k) = \chi(G-e, k) - \chi(G/e, k),\end{equation} but I'm not sure what exactly.
Any help is appreciated.

My apologies the first one was a typo. But isn’t the second one correct? e.g. theorem 1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.08154

The second equation is correct. One other thing you need to be careful about though: in the deletion-contraction relation for t(G), we consider G / e to be the contraction where parallel edges are not identified, whereas in the deletion-contraction relation for the chromatic number, we do identify parallel edges when considering G / e. So be careful about parallel edges and self-loops when working with G / e on this question.

In this answer, take $G / e$ to mean the contraction of $G$ by $e$, but crucially we identify parallel edges.
With this definition of contraction, I claim that:
$$t(G) \ge t(G - e) + t(G / e).$$
For this, we do the usual proof, but now note that the number of spanning trees of $G$ that contain $e$ could be more than the number of spanning trees of $G / e$ (or another way to think about it: by taking the convention that we identify parallel edges, this can only decrease the value of $t(G / e)$).
Now let $a_1(G)$ be the coefficient $a_1$ of $\chi_G$ as defined in the question. Because of the $(-1)^{n - i}$ in front of $a_i$ in its definition, and using the deletion-contraction relation for $\chi_G$, we get:
$$a_1(G) = a_1(G - e) + a(G / e).$$
Then note if the base cases are true, the induction step will work:
$$\begin{align*}
t(G)
&\ge t(G - e) + t(G / e) \\
&\ge a_1(G - e) + a_1(G / e) \\
&= a_1(G)
\end{align*}$$
So we now check the base cases, i.e. when $G$ has no edges. In this case, $t(G) = 0$ if $|G| > 1$, and $t(G) = 1$ otherwise. We have $\chi_G(k) = k^{|G|}$, so $a_1(G) = 1$ if $|G| = 1$ and $a_1(G) = 0$ otherwise. So the base cases hold.
